# html2pdf() javascript in laravel total graph without overflow x-y

Tags: javascript, laravel

Hello to the whole community,
I'm using html2pdf javascript to extrapolate graphs created in Laravel, but the problem is that on a graph that's too large I had to set x-y overflow for the scroll, now the half graph comes out in the PDF.
How can I solve to have everything in the PDF?
This is the graph and the code
thank you so much community..

[image]

```
<script>
    $('#btn-one').click(function() {
        let div = document.querySelector(".tutto");
        var opt = {
            margin: [0, 8, 0, 0],
            pagebreak: { mode: 'avoid-all' }
         };
        html2pdf().from(div).set(opt).save('dashboard-pers-layout-1.pdf');
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: _"This is the graph"_ - can't tell from just a screenshot, what this _actually_ is. Is the whole thing one image? Or is this actually HTML content?

Comment: yes this is the graph.. if you want, post the html too! basically in the app there is x y overflow to scroll down and to the left and if I want to save the PDF it doesn't remove the overflow it stays like this. I would like to see all the results in the PDF instead

Comment: I asked what it is made of, because with an image you could have simply limited the max-width to 100%. But if it is HTML, then you will either have to find a way to scale this down so that it will all fit without a scrollbar being necessary - or find a different way of displaying this in your PDF altogether.

Comment: Yes, you're right, do you happen to have any ideas?

Comment: I guess your easiest option would probably be to get the full width of that content inside the scrollable element, and the width of the page - and then do the math, to translate this into an appropriate factor to use with `transform: scale(...)`(Although transformations leave the original space an element needed, reserved - so your element shrinking in height as well, might leave some extra whitespace.)

Comment: Tried it doesn't work with this property

Comment: Possible that html2pdf does not support this. Then you'll have to find another way to reduce the size/width of that content - smaller margins/paddings, smaller font sizes, ...

Comment: Or maybe actually allow the content to break into multiple lines. What you got there isn't much of an actual "graph" to begin with, rather just a list of properties with a yes/no indicator ... Viewers should still be able to interpret this correctly, if you allowed the content under "Maggazino Scaffalle A A1" to display in two or more lines, I suppose ...?

Comment: yes, exactly, but in the PDF it appears as in the graph and not all the data because it is omitted from the scroll with overflow

Comment: I attach a pdf screen shot

Comment: see the pdf screen... I would like all the results to be there both horizontally and vertically as if there were no scroll... instead the overflow is also placed in the pdf... because in reality if there wasn't a list it would be very long

Comment: What do you mean, _"yes, exactly"_? I gave you a suggestion what to _change_, to avoid your issue in the PDF. Not sure why you talk about the screenshot and what the problem is, again now - that was already perfectly clear.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your suggestion well.. could you tell me exactly what you're referring to?

Comment: I would like it to stay like this but without the x and y overflow
If I do it all over again, the graph no longer makes sense

Comment: What I was saying is, just allow this to break into multiple lines, so that scrollbars won't be necessary any more. (If you want it for the PDF only, then do that via a class you apply directly before you generate the PDF, or work with a clone of the element.) If you don't want that, and you want it to look the same in the PDF, as it does on the page - then you have no other option, than to make "everything" (margins, paddings, font size, maybe even the image(?) dimensions of those checkbox-indicators) smaller ...